# how can I get ssl\tls version supported by server in java

Tags: java

How can I get ssl\tls version supported by server in java

I use socket and getEnabledProtocols() method
but this method doesn't return versions detailed for example it return  SSLv3, TLSv1, but I want get TLSv1.0, TLSv1.1 etc
Thanks

Comment: If it doesn't return TLSV1.1 etc it isn't supported. What JRE version are you using?

Comment: What server? JBoss? Tomcat? Glassfish?

Comment: @PeterRader The server is irrelevant. The JRE version is all that matters, and the JSSE implementation name.

Comment: TLSV1.1 version supports
JRE version is 7

Comment: @user3523843 So why did you write `server` in the question if the server is irrelevant?

Comment: @PeterRader I don't know server is irrelevant or not. I have checked for example https://pentagontours.osd.milit and it supports TLS 1.2,TLS 1.1,TLS 1.0,SSL3 (you can see https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=pentagontours.osd.mil) but my code return only SSLv3,TLSv1. I need  detailed info